# What do the partition table types and flags mean in the output of parted?

Tags: partition, gpt, parted, mbr, loop-device

In the output of `sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: WD My Passport 0748 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


Model: WDC WD25 00BEVS-08VAT2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  250GB  250GB  ntfs               msftdata


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/VG-home: 452GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  452GB  452GB  ext4
```

Does partition table type "msdos" mean MBR? Isn't it that MBR can't hold a 4GB file, but I can copy a 4GB  Windows 8.1 .iso file to it?

Is partition table type "gpt" good for an external hard drive?

What does "Partition Table: loop" mean? Is it relate to loop device?

What does "msftdata" in Flags mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

“msdos” does mean MBR, yes. That has no relation to the file systems used, which is where a file size limit would come from.

GPT is fine for an external drive.

The “loop” partition type is used by `parted` for raw disk access, *i.e.* when there’s no partition table.

“msftdata” is a `parted` flag used to indicate that the partition uses [the basic data GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition), not one of the Linux-specific GUIDs.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "The “loop” partition type is used by parted for raw disk access, i.e. when there’s no partition table". In LVM, does a VG necessarily not have a partition table? Does a LV necessarily  not have a partition table? (2) “msdos does mean MBR," Isn't it that MBR can't hold a 4GB file, but why can I copy a 4GB Windows 8.1 .iso file to it?

Comment: The MBR can only hold 512 bytes. No more. No less. But you can "copy" a 4GB Windows 8.1 .iso file to it, it won't be a great loss ;-\

Comment: Is max file size limit imposed by filesystem (fat32) or partition type (MBR) or both?

Comment: (1) As has been mentioned previously by others, you can add a partition table pretty much anywhere you want, but it won’t be all that useful. From LVM’s perspective, a VG doesn’t have a partition table, nor does an LV. (2) I said that a file size limit comes from the file system used: MBR doesn’t impose any file size limit in the file systems contained in partitions in an MBR table. When you copy a file, you’re not copying it to an MBR partition table.

Comment: Thanks. `/dev/mapper/VG-home` is a LV, and `VG` is a VG. Why does `parted` output treat a LV as if it were a disk, and not show VG like disk at all? Isn't a LV more similar to a partition than a disk, and a VG similar to a disk? So does speaking a LV having a partition table make  as little sense as speaking a partition having a partition table ?

Comment: `parted` ignores VGs because there aren’t any device nodes corresponding to VGs, whereas there are for LVs. Comparing a VG to a disk is somewhat limiting, as is comparing an LV to a partition, but yes, a VG is more similar to a disk than an LV, and an LV is more similar to a partition than a VG. I’m not sure I understand your last question; LVs are more versatile than partitions and can be used in contexts where it makes sense for them to have partition tables themselves (*e.g.* as disk images for VMs), but you wouldn’t use the partition table directly.